# Set HTTP protocol version in HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, .net-4.5

I need to make a request to a webservice that uses HTTP version 1.0. Im using `HttpClient` , But I cant see any option to set HTTP version.

Where can i set the request version?

Comment: Out of interest, may I ask why?

Comment: Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Icemanind, the example is using httpwebrequest, which but i use httpclient in my application.

Comment: @poke, strange, but i don't know why either, i just follow their api,but the api is using httpwebrequest

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to set the version you'll have to create an instance of [`HttpRequestMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and set its `Version` property which you pass to [`HttpClient.SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx). You can use the helper `HttpVersion` utility class:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage 
{
    Version = HttpVersion.Version10
}; 

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Comment: My UWP app has the HttpRequestMessage but it does not contain a proprty called 'Version'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP version is sent as a header in every request, so it is set in the message sent by System.Net.Http.HttpClient: see the [ProtocolVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class.