# Xamarin.Forms sending HttpClient GET or POST request to API with TLS 1.3

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tls1.3

Any idea what is the workaround on my App. My app works perfectly before when our server using TLS 1.2,After we upgraded to TLS 1.3, all HttpClient POST and GET Request are not working and get the exception

**INNER EXCEPTION**

```sh
Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xcb444f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0xcb172b48:0x00000001)
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLProtocolException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xcb444f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0xcb172b48:0x00000001)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
```

Below image is the advance Android Option configuration I used.
[image]

Below snippets is ny HttpClient setup for HttpClient request.

```cs
public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }

public ApiServiceBase()
{
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = BaseAddress };
    this.httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

[image]

- Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.2
- .Net Framework Version 4.8

Comment: Add the exception you got and the inner exception also.

Comment: Yes, please provide the inner exception as well as @o_w mentioned. You can also try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887091/how-to-make-calls-to-http2-on-xamarin-forms/62394603#62394603

Comment: "the ssl connection could not be established see inner exception. authentication failed"

That's the inner exception, It's occurred when we upgrade our server TLS from 1.2 to 1.3, It's only happen in Android platform in my Xamarin Forms. I do a lot of research including James Montemagno suggestions but it won't work.

Comment: Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xcb444f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0xcb172b48:0x00000001)
  --- End of managed Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLProtocolException stack trace ---
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xcb444f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION

Comment: I already post the detailed InnerException in my question above. Kindly check, please. Thanks

Comment: What type of project is `Mobile.Client.APIService`? E.g. Is it .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: Hi Brandon, Yes It is .Net Standard 2.0. All Libraries I used are .Net standard 2.0

Comment: Hi @parpar! Have you found a solutions for this?