# HttpRequest Http 2.0

Tags: c#, http2, httpconnection

I am trying to make a HTTP/2.0 request but cant get it to work. According to this and other posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776383/18171693 .NET > 3.0 shall support it but I can not get it to work.

```
       Debug.WriteLine("Version:"+ Environment.Version.ToString());

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://http2.akamai.com/demo")
        {
            Version = new Version(2, 0)
        };

        var x = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

The code above generates:

```
Version:4.0.30319.42000
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using .NET-Core.

The version you're using - `4.0.30319.42000` - corresponds to .NET *Framework* 4.6+, not .NET core.

From [How to: Determine which .NET Framework versions are installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed):

> The common language runtime (CLR), which manages and executes your
> app's code. A single CLR version typically supports multiple .NET
> Framework versions. For example, CLR version 4.0.30319.xxxxx where
> *xxxxx* is less than 42000, supports .NET Framework versions 4 through
> 4.5.2. **CLR version greater than or equal to 4.0.30319.42000 supports .NET Framework versions starting with .NET Framework 4.6**.

Only Http versions 1/1.1 are supported in .NET Framework, however this question [How to make the .net HttpClient use http 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685151/how-to-make-the-net-httpclient-use-http-2-0) has some workarounds.

I've tested your code, which works for me on .NET core 3.1 and .NET 6. [Demo in .NET 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5R4yX8)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I installed .NET 6 and then it  worked fine. At a first glance i cant find the charts control in the Windows Form though, but I guess that s another problem :-)